# LaTeX Error: File `tikz.sty' not found

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{atchi}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-6,0)--(0,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to fix this error:

> LaTeX Error: File `tikz.sty` not found.

Comment: Which tex distribution do you have?

Comment: Is this the same question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472982/someone-to-help-me-when-i-use-tikz-usepakage-it-will-display-this-problem ?

Comment: yes it's the same

Comment: i have the distrubution 2.9

Comment: @MeriemDivitcha You mean MikTeX 2.9?

Comment: I guess you didn't install `pgf`. This the  MiKTeX package which contains `tikz.sty`, and it is not installed by default by the basic installer.

Comment: @Bernard where can i have the package of tikz !

Comment: Install pgf with MiKTeX Package Manager.

Comment: @Bernard how ! i'm new in latex i don't know how to do it

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call `MiKTeX Console` in the apps of Windows.

Then you have to choose using user mode or admin mode (I have an admin installation, so you will see admin mode in the following ...)

After that you have to click on `packages` (see left red circle):

[image: miktex console]

Now type `tikz` where the red arrow points to.

Now click on the symbol marked with the right red circle to get a list of installable packages containing `tikz` in the filename.

At last click on the +-sign before `tikz` to install the selected packages.

Do the same with `pgf`:

[image: pgf installation]

Comment: Following these instructions, I get 'A connection to ims.jit.ac.in could not be established.

More info: https://miktex.org/kb/fix-couldnt-connect'

Comment: @ManjoyDas Please ask a new question and add which version you are using. Have you tried to use another repository?

Comment: here's my question :https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594588/latex-error-file-amsthm-sty-not-found-usepackage

Answer (score -3):

Such errors occur from time to time with newer versions of Miktex and Latex packages, and while there are some fine solutions, often the good ol' reinstall of Miktex turns to be the least time consuming. (I mean a fresh install of the latest MiKTeX version.) Not to mention that it's often caused by a bug in Miktex, and then what you would be looking for is a workaround which might, or might not work.

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Sorry that is not true. In this case the basic MiKTeX does not include TiKz -- therefore the error!

Comment: Thank! Yes, the basic MiKTeX doesn't include TiKz, after the fresh install all packages would need to be installed again. However, after the fresh install all new packages are installed smoothly - without any errors. That's just my humble experience. I believe it's because of everything being up-to-date, including the package repository.