# LaTeX error: File `amsthm.sty' not found. \usepackage

Tags: errors, miktex

I was trying to draw a switching circuit using `circuitikz` package. But I got an error that `circuitikz.sty` file is missing. Then I tried to update MiKTeX Console having an idea how to install packages from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473019/latex-error-file-tikz-sty-not-found/473043?noredirect=1#comment1491306_473043). Following this, I received another error that **'A connection to ims.jit.ac.in could not be established. More info: miktex.org/kb/fix-couldnt-connect'**. Then I uninstalled the MiKTeX (version most probably 2.9) and reinstalled the newest (version 20.12). Now I am getting the error : **File `amsthm.sty' not found. \usepackage**.

Everytime I go for an update, whether it's miktex update or any package update, I get 'SSL connect error' and the copy error button gives me:

> 'GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION
> ReportDate: 2021-04-27 04:33:38
> CurrentVersion: 21.2
> SetupDate: 2021-04-27 03:46:00
> SetupVersion: 21.2
> Configuration: Regular
> GitInfo: 7a7e645 / 2021-02-20 10:38:14
> OS: Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit, Service Pack 1, build 7601
> SharedSetup: no
> LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Users\MANJOY\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64
> PathOkay: yes
> LastUpdateCheck: not yet
> LastUpdate: not yet
> LastUpdateDb: not yet
> SystemAdmin: yes
> RootPrivileges: no
> AdminMode: no
> Root0: C:\Users\MANJOY\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
> Root1: C:\Users\MANJOY\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
> Root2: C:\Users\MANJOY\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
> Root3: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
> Root4: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> UserInstall: C:\Users\MANJOY\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
> UserConfig: C:\Users\MANJOY\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
> UserData: C:\Users\MANJOY\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
> CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
> CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
> Invokers: .../RdrCEF/RdrCEF/explorer
> The following issues were detected:
> 1: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.
> ERROR DETAILS
> Program: C:\Users\MANJOY\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-console.exe
> Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\CurlWebSession.cpp:247
> Error: SSL connect error
> Details:
> code: 35
> url: [https://ims.jit.ac.in/repo/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/circuitikz.tar.lzma'](https://ims.jit.ac.in/repo/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/circuitikz.tar.lzma%27)

**Note: I am also not able to check update for the new MiKTeX version.**

Comment: Seems the repo you are trying to connect to is down (currently https://ims.jit.ac.in/repo/tex-archive/ shows that it is unavailable). Try changing the repository/mirror to a different site https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56783/how-can-i-change-the-package-repository

Comment: @WillieWong I changed the package source by setting a proxy. Since `ims.jit.ac.in` was not working, i chose `mirrors.sustech.edu.cn` from China. Will it cause any legal issue?

Comment: IANAL, but all repositories listed at https://miktex.org/pkg/repositories should be publicly available.

Comment: @WillieWong after choosing the above proxy, when I set back to `random package repository on the internet`, again the error message is popping up which means that the problem is not solved completely. Would you like to suggest something for that?

Comment: This appears to be the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/594597 which has a workable answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Miktex and package update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594597/miktex-and-package-update)