# Miktex and package update

Tags: packages, miktex, miktex-update

Initially the issue was `circuitikz.sty` was missing. Then I tried to update package from MiKTeX console `package` option and I got the error

> SSL connect error

and the code was

> code="35", url="https://ims.jit.ac.in/repo/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma"

Then I uninstalled MiKTeX and reinstalled it. After that MiKTeX console is not updating and doesn't let any package to be updated. When I try to check update for console, it shows
[image]

When I try to update packages, it shows:
[image]

**Also the Texstudio has stopped the compilation**. This is becoming a notorious problem for my purpose. Any sort of suggestion is welcome!

Comment: If there are connection problems it seldom helps to deinstall and reinstall MiKTeX as the new MiKTeX will have the same connection problem. And it can make the situation worse as the new version hasn't all the packages and updates you installed already.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I changed the package source by setting a proxy. Since `ims.jit.ac.in` was not working, i chose `mirrors.sustech.edu.cn` from China. Will it cause any legal issue?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea.

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner yes. But I don't understand to vote for closing this question

Comment: You did not accept the provided answer and I assumed the question is not active anymore. If the question is answered then accept the provided answer. There was also no upvote for the provided answer. So to me the status is unclear.

Comment: Otherwise the question will remain unanswered and open. I just tried to either close or answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the site https://ims.jit.ac.in/repo/tex-archive is having some issues. You can change the repository that MikTeX updates from by following the instructions at [How can I change the package repository?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56783/how-can-i-change-the-package-repository)

Comment: Yours and Ulrike's answers are quite right. I replied on Ulrike's comment. Please serve your suggestions too.