# The document doesnt compile when i include \usepackage{hyperref}

Tags: hyperref, compiling

I am trying to make my document navigable by including the `hyperref` package. But, when doing so, I find  the error:

> ​! LaTex error: File `refcount.sty' not found.
>
> Type X to quit or  ro proceed,
> or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
>
> Enter file name:

What can I do to make the document, including `hyperref` package, compilable?

Comment: It works for me … // To avoid reactions like this please post your code. Thank you.

Comment: install the refcount package.

Comment: If you don't know, how to install a package, see, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473019/277964 for MiKTeX or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28627/277964 for Linux distribution's version of TeX Live or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/368703/277964 for Vanilla TeX Live and MacTeX.

Comment: My code is: \documentclass{article} \usepackage{hyperref}\begin{document} hola \end{document}

Comment: Unfortunately LaTeX error messages are often cryptic, but "file X not found" have not occult or esoteric meanings: The program cannot reach the right path to X for some reason, or X  is not where it should be, for some other reasons, being the  most probably reason that simply it was not installed.